# Angular 2 and RxJS: How to change HTTP call that returns Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-observables

How do I change this function to work with the JSON change described below?

The current function returns an `Observable<User[]>`, but with the new JSON, the new `admin` object has been added. The new function should successfully observe both the existing `users` array and the new `admins` array.

```
getData(): Observable<User[]> {
  return this.http
    .get('www.example.com/api/users)
    .map((r: Response) => r.json().assets.users as User[]);
}
```

JSON returned from `/api/users`

```
{
"assets": {
    "users": [
        // user objects
    ]
}
```

...now returns two arrays, `users` and `admins`.

```
{
"assets": {
    "users": [
        // array of user objects
    ],
    "admins": [
        // array of admin objects
    ]

}
```

Please assume that my code does have `User` and `Admin` classes already created that correctly reflect the properties of the related JSON objects returned.

Comment: so what do you want? not clear

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I added more details to the beginning of the question.

Comment: _new function should successfully observe_ - by observe do you mean return objects from both arrays? or return two arrays?

Comment: The 1st one: return objects from both arrays.

Comment: but this is not how it's working, it returns an array of users, not users objects

Comment: I'll think about exactly what I want. Maybe I don't know how to say it in the necessary amount of detail. But, instead of just getting users, now I want to be able to get users and admins, with a single call to the back-end. I don't really care whether it's two arrays, one object, or something else. I just want to get the new admins data also.

Comment: So what you are looking for is an Array containing both users and admins in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have a few options how to return the data:

```
getData(): Observable<User[]> {
  return this.http
    .get('www.example.com/api/users')
    .map((r: Response) => { 
         const assets = r.json().assets;
         return {
             users: assets.users as User[],
             admins: assets.admins as Admin[]
         }
     });
}
```

Or like this:

```
getData(): Observable<User[]> {
  return this.http
    .get('www.example.com/api/users')
    .map((r: Response) => { 
         return [
             assets.users as User[],
             assets.admins as Admin[]
         ]
     });
}
```

Or like this:

```
getData(): Observable<User[]> {
  return this.http
    .get('www.example.com/api/users')
    .map((r: Response) => { 
         return [
             ...assets.users as User[],
             ...assets.admins as Admin[]
         ]
     });
}
```

Comment: To explain what's happening here: `.map()` returns a new array using the values from the array it is attached to. Therefor, in order to return a new array containing both users and admins, a function needs to be used in `.map()` to transform the response data into the new desired array.

Comment: Can I just say this? You two rock! Great answer and wonderful explanation for an RxJS newb. I'm going to work on implementing this now. I hope my edit helped. I tried to follow the guidelines and "show research effort" but I might have gotten lost down the rabbit hole a bit.

Comment: @Maximus can you explain the ellipses in "...assets" in your final answer?

Comment: @JerryHuckins, sure, this is called spread syntax and is explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator). Consider accepting my answer if it helped. Thanks

Comment: @Maximus I accepted your answer. If you found the question useful, please consider upvoting it.

Comment: @Maximus I just noticed in your answer, on all 3 examples, the ".get(" lines have opening single quotes and not closing quotes. It doesn't concern me, but just for future viewers, I thought I'd let you know. Thanks again for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return both users and admins in the same array, the following code should do the trick:

```
getData(): Observable<User[]> {
  return this.http
    .get('www.example.com/api/users)
    .map((r: Response) => {
        var results = r.json();
        return results.assets.users.concat(results.assets.admins);
    }
}
```

With the following data:

```
{
"assets": {
    "users": [
        { "name": "bob" }, { "name": "john" }
    ],
    "admins": [
        { "name": "jill" }, { "name": "donald" }
    ]

}
```

The result would be equal to:

```
[ { "name": "bob" }, { "name": "john" }, { "name": "jill" }, { "name": "donald" } ]
```

As explained in my comment for @Maximus answer, `.map()` is used to transform an array into a new one, which is why you want to feed a function to `.map()` to tell it what array you are looking for.